# DevExpress.XtraEditors. Выпадающий список ранее открытых сайтов

Tags: c#, winforms, devexpress, chromium

В DevExpress.XtraEditors.ButtonEdit в событии SpinDown в ButtonEdit необходимо сделать выпадающий список ранее открытых файлов, основа браузера Chromium.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения][image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
 private void TxtUrl_ButtonClick(object sender, ButtonPressedEventArgs e)
        {   
            //button ok
            if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Button.Tag) == 1)
            {
                var chrome = tabControl.SelectedTabPage.Controls[0] as ChromiumWebBrowser;
                chrome?.Load(txtUrl.Text);
            }
            //button SpinDown
            else if (Convert.ToInt32(e.Button.Tag) == 2)
            {
                {
                   //        button SpinDown   выподающий список ранее открытых сайтов             
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Вопрос в том как из `ButtonEdit` вывести выпадающий список (почему не `LookUpEdit`) или в том, как из хромиума получить список сайтов? Уточните, пожалуйста.

Comment: В ButtonEdit. Добавил картинку

Comment: Не пробовали для этого использовать `LookUpEdit`? У него сразу есть выпадающий список и в него также можно добавить разные кнопки.

Comment: LookUpEdit не пробовал, как поместить в выпадающий список, список посещенных сайтов?